# custom filename with .htaccess and db update at download

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm using curently .htaccess to download files from my server with custom filename using RewriteEngine.
My rule looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^d/([0-9]+)/(.*).jpg files/photo-$1.jpg
```

$1 is the file id that it is stored in db also.
Everything work fine but i want to update my db when the file is downloaded, i need a request to be sent to download.php?id=$1 when the rule is accesed.
Is there a way to do that with .htaccess and RewriteEngine ? I searched a lot but i didn't find any solution.
Any help will be highly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> i need a request to be sent to download.php?id=$1

Then rewrite the request to `download.php?id=$1` instead of `files/$2-$1.jpg`. Your PHP script must then serve the actual image (ie. `files/<name>-<id>.jpg`) in the response, instead of directly rewriting to the file as you are doing currently.

Comment: I have thinked at that but then i will lose the custom filename, I don't want to use ReadFile in php to change filename, it will load the server too much, .htaccess is the best way to rename them.

Comment: @B13 You won't "lose the custom filename". `^d/([0-9]+)/(.*).jpg` is your "custom filename" and mod_rewrite is still rewriting that request. However, you will need to use `readfile()` in PHP to serve the file if using `.htaccess`. An alternative... if you have access to the server config then you can configure a custom log file for such requests (but this won't use your `download.php` script).